# Need help decyphering regex re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I'm hopeless with regex and wonder if someone can help me decipher what this bit of python regex is doing in plain English please?

```
text = re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>','  ',strHTML)
```

I know that any matches are being replaced by '  ' but I'm lost on what the regex expression is matching against.
As I see it, its matching all instances of '<',  is ignoring all instances of '>' via '[^>]' but I've no idea why you would do that as it shouldn't be matched to anything else anyway.
I gather that the '*?>' is matching any block of text with a '>' in it such as 'p>'

Can someone help me with a definitive breakdown please?

Comment: Take a look: https://www.debuggex.com/r/fQNgfILsUTaaqoSj

Comment: My frustrations ended with this site: http://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it removes all tags: `<[^>]*?>`

- `<` - matches `<` character
- `[^>]*?`

  - `*?` - repeats preceding block 0 or more times (in fact `?` is redundant here, because it impossible to match more than minimum amount of characters)
  - `[^>]` - matches any non `>` character
- `>` - matches `>` character

In short idea is to find start of the tag, then find all (if any) character that are not end of the tag. Then find end of the tag.

Also there is service that can generate text description automatically http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/